# Potion Tier 2 bug with toItemStack() method

Tags: java, minecraft, potion

this code doesn't work when I put tier_two or 2. However, if I put it to 1 or One it works. Does someone have an idea ?

```
Potion heal = new Potion(PotionType.INSTANT_HEAL, Tier.TWO, true);
contents[3] = heal.toItemStack(1);
```

For information the content is an ItemMeta [] which I use to create a kit

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a integer as the effect "strength". I don't know what the Tier belongs to, but maybe that will interrupt it?

Try to use:

```
Potion heal = new Potion(PotionType.INSTANT_HEAL, 2, false)
```